# double hashing with collision on first and second hash functions-java

Tags: java, hash, double-hashing

For double hashing, if there is a collision with the first hash function, you'd use the second hash function, but what if there is still a collision? For example, let's say a hash table is size 15 and the hash function is `(key + 3) % 15` and the second hash function is `((key % 8) / 3) + 2`. Let's say "insert 59" goes to index 2 by the first hash function but there already is a key there. The second hash function would bring it to 3 but let's say there already is a value there too. Where would 59 be inserted on the hash table and why? Thanks

I specifically want to use double hashing, not chained hashing or linear probing.

Comment: Is this Java-specific?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the way we calculate the second hash function, since for every probe(unavailability of slot) you need to have a new hash function and it is not feasible.

Generic Second Hash function would be of type,

H1(x) - first hash function,
H2(x) - second hash function

First time we try for following slot - H1(x),

next probe would be - H1(x)+H2(x),

next probe H1(x)+2*H2(x)   ........  H1(x)+n*H2(x)

Answer (score 0):

The second hash function does not calculate the new index on its own, rather, we use a combination of both the functions using a collision number `-- i`.
Say you have `H1(k)` and `H2(k)` then the combination would be

```
H = (H1(k) + i*H2(k))%n
```

And we keep incrementing `i`.

Answer (score -2):

This is implementation specific, but typically you'd use a linked list or other flexible data structure to managed colliding data.

From the java.util.HashMap javadoc:

> It uses a hash-bucket approach; that is, hash collisions are handled
>      by linking the new node off of the pre-existing node (or list of
>     nodes).  In this manner, techniques such as linear probing (which
>     can cause primary clustering) and rehashing (which does not fit very
>      well with Java's method of precomputing hash codes) are avoided.
>    Under ideal circumstances (no collisions), HashMap offers O(1)
>    performance on most operations (`containsValue()` is,
>    of course, O(n)).  In the worst case (all keys map to the same
>   hash code -- very unlikely), most operations are O(n).

Comment: The question is about double hashing which is an alternative strategy to having a linked list. The OP says he doesn't want linking.